# php -v shows different version than phpinfo() on IIS

Tags: php, windows, iis-10

Sorry if this question is a repeat but I could not find the answer.

```
php -v
PHP 7.3.15 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2020 12:45:47) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
```

Chrome opening a page with `phpinfo(): PHP Version 7.2.19`

I just tried to install PHP `7.3` but a `phpinfo()` in the browser is still showing `PHP 7.2` and so not it is not using the new `7.3` version like the cli is.  How can I get Windows IIS to use the same version of PHP as the cli?

(I am using Windows 10 and Windows IIS-10)

Comment: Try this: https://www.itnota.com/upgrading-php-7-2-windows-iis/

Comment: thanks, that was it